# Cómo validar campos opcionales en flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, aplicación-movil

quiero saber como puedo hacer la validación de campos opcionales, por ejemplo, si hay dos campos de numero de telefono, que el telefono 2 sea opcional, osea que sino se escribe nada el botón se habilte pero si se escribe algo que lo valide tal cual como lo hace el telefono 1, con los stream y el combineLatest de rxdart, he intentado pero no me sale, si lo dejo en blanco no se habilita el botón, tengo que escirbir algo y luego volver a borrar y ahora si lo habilita.

Dejo la validación  que esoy haciendo:

```
final validatePhoneTwo = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (phonetwo, sink) {
    Pattern pattern = r'^(?:[+0][1-9])?[0-9]{8,12}$';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (phonetwo.length == 0) {
      sink.add(phonetwo);
    } else if (phonetwo.length > 0 && regExp.hasMatch(phonetwo)) {
      sink.add(phonetwo);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Telefono solo permite numeros');
    }
  });
```

Cuando se muestra el formulario y completo todos los campos menos el telefono 2, no se habilita el boton, imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se habilta si escribo algo y lo borro, iamgen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ampliar, aquí es donde veo los campos, si yo dejo el telefono 2 en blanco al presentarse por primera vez el formulario, no me habilita el botón, hasta que escribo algo y luego lo borra.

```
 Stream<bool> get formValidStream => Rx.combineLatest9(
      nameRegisterStream,
      firstSurnameStream,
      secondSurnameStream,
      identificationStream,
      phoneOneStream,
      phoneTwoStream,
      sectorStream,
      emailRegisterStream,
      passwordRegisterStream,
      (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo necesitas validar un campo opcional, para eso es necesario utilizar el Widget Form que nos permite utilizar las validaciones al momento de requerir guardarlas, puedes hacer algo como esto:

1.- Para el primer campo valida de forma normal con una función que retorne un valor.

2.- En el segundo campo valida que si no está vació entonces procedes a validar como lo haces en el primer campo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Example'),
        ),
        body: _Form(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Form extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final TextEditingController _required = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _optional = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: _required,
                validator: _validateRequired,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _optional,
                validator: _validateOptional,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _save(),
                child: Text('Ingresar'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _save() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) print('Saved');
    print('Error');
  }

  String? _validateRequired(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'El dato es requerido';
    return null;
  }

  String? _validateOptional(String? value) {
    if ((value != null && value.isNotEmpty) && !_myValidator(value)!)
      return 'Error con el número';
    return null;
  }

  bool? _myValidator(String? value) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Alex, gracias por la respuesta, voy a intenatrlo como usted indica pero como le comentaba, uso bloc para ver lo lo que se esta escribiendo e ir cambiando el mensaje y habilitar o deshabilitar el botón.